# Extracting values from zipped list and tuple at the same time

Tags: python

I have a list of tuple and a list of scalar value and I want to extract values from them at the same time.
e.g.

```
>>> a = [('type1', 1), ('type2', 2)]
>>> b = [res1, res2]
>>> for ai, bi in zip(a, b):
...     ai1, ai2 = ai
...     print(ai1, ai2, bi)
...
type1 1 res1
type2 2 res2
```

How can we avoid step of re splitting `ai` in loop itself.

```
# something like this (This does not work though)
>>> for ai1, ai2, bi in zip(a, b):
...     ai1, ai2 = ai
...     print(ai1, ai2, bi)
```

Comment: `for (ai1, ai2), bi in zip(a, b):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the appropriate parentheses:

```
>>> a = [('type1', 1), ('type2', 2)]
>>> b = ["FOO", "BAR"]
>>> for (ai1, ai2), bi in zip(a, b):
...     print(ai1, ai2, bi)
...
type1 1 FOO
type2 2 BAR
```

Note, for iterable unpacking, square brackets and parentheses work the same:

```
>>> for [ai1, ai2], bi in zip(a, b):
...     print(ai1, ai2, bi)
...
type1 1 FOO
type2 2 BAR
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use brackets to achieve exactly that.

```
for (ai1, ai2), bi in zip(a, b):
    print(ai1, ai2, bi)
```